# Screen not changing after firestore realtime value changes using conditionals

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**NOTE: DO TELL ME IF SOMETHINGIS MISSING.**

So, I am using firestore realtime queries onsnapshot etc. in the HomeHelperScreen, this screen also contains the RideDetailsScreen too. When i change the firestore values using the bookRide function:

```js
function bookRide(driver_onesignalIdprop, rideId, no_of_seats) {
  
      const groupRef = firestore().collection('Passengers').doc(auth().currentUser.uid);
      groupRef.get().then((docSnapshot) => {
        // Example passenger object
        // Example passenger object
        const passenger = {
          name: auth().currentUser.displayName,
          email: auth().currentUser.email,
          paymentStatus: "not paid",
          reportSubmitted: false,
          uid: auth().currentUser.uid,//checking along with no. of seats
          //if seats > 1 and reportSubmitted==false and paymentStatus==not paid
          main_booker: 'yes',
        };
  
        // Firestore document representing a ride
        const rideDocRef = firestore().collection("Ride").doc(rideId);
  
        rideDocRef.set(
          {
            passengers: {
              [passenger.uid]: passenger,
            },
          },
          { merge: true }
        )
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Passenger added successfully");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error adding passenger:", error);
          });
  
        firestore()
          .collection('Ride')
          .doc(itemObj.key)
          .update({
            main_booker_uid: auth().currentUser.uid,
            request_status: 'pending',//acceptance by driver?
            reserved_seats: no_of_seats,
            passengerDownloadURL: docSnapshot.data().downloadURL,
            passenger_onesignal_id: docSnapshot.data().playerId,
            passenger_name: auth().currentUser.displayName,
            passenger_email: auth().currentUser.email,
            seats: firestore.FieldValue.increment(-no_of_seats),
            hidden: true,//not visible to other non-members.
          })
          .then(() => {
            alert('Ride booked!');
          });
      });
  
    }
```

the PairingCodeScreen does not show up

```js
      {passengerHasBookedRideAlone
        && rideActive
        && rideComplete == false ?
        //was working
        (//add many other conditions.
          <>
            <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="Ridestart" component={Ridestartedscreen} />
          </>
        ) :
        passengerHasBookedRideMultiple
          && rideActive
          && rideComplete == false ?
          //was working
          (//add many other conditions.
            <>
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="Ridestart" component={Ridestartedscreen} />
            </>
          ) :
          passengerHasBookedRideAlone && rideComplete == false ? (//add many other conditions.
            <>
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="Pending" component={PendingScreen} />
            </>//was working
          ) : passengerHasBookedRideMultiple && rideActive == false
            && rideComplete == false ? (//add many other conditions.
            <>
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="Pairing" component={PairingCodeScreen} />
            </>//for 

          ) : passengerHasBookedRideAlone
            && rideComplete == true && paymentStatus == false ? (//add many other conditions.
            <>
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="PaymentRide" component={PaymentScreen} />
            </>//for 
          ) : passengerHasBookedRideMultiple
            && rideComplete == true && paymentStatus == false ? (//add many other conditions.
            <>
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="PaymentRide" component={PaymentScreen} />
            </>//for 
          ) : passengerHasBookedRideAlone
            && rideActive == false
            && rideComplete
            && reportSubmitted == false ? (//add many other conditions.
            <>
              {/* this should be  */}
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="RIDEcomplete" component={Ridecompletescreen} />
            </>
          ) : passengerHasBookedRideMultiple
            && rideActive == false
            && rideComplete
            && reportSubmitted == false ? (//add many other conditions.
            <>
              {/* this should be  */}
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="RIDEcomplete" component={Ridecompletescreen} />
            </>
          ) : (//
            <>
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="Startlocation" component={StartLocationScreen} />
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="Endlocation" component={EndLocationScreen} />
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="Directions" component={DirectionsScreen} />
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="ListOfRidesHelper" component={ListOfRidesHelperScreen} />
              <HomeHelperStack.Screen name="RideDetails" component={RideDetailsScreen} />
            </>
          )}
```

i have tried logging all the values and the checking them but the app would only show this screen only on refreshing it.

**NOTE: DO TELL ME IF SOMETHING needs more EXPLANATION.**

Comment: Do you mind editing your question and omitting the notes where you demand guidance? This is a Q&A site, quality questions yield quality answers, it's not a get free help site. Thanks.

Comment: the note was trying to say that tell (guide) me if something in the code is missing so that you guys can understand it easily.

Comment: I understand, I commented to let you know it comes off as rude and encouraged you to omit it for better reception of your question